# MySQL Top10 List with counter using only one query

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I am actually working on a Top10 invites list, displaying users which invited most other users.

That's the database table:

```
user_id  | name       | invited_by
-----------------------------------
1        | john       | 0
2        | maria      | 1
3        | johanna    | 1
4        | natasha    | 1
5        | julia      | 4
6        | antonio    | 4
7        | matthias   | 5
8        | daniel     | 5
9        | michelle   | 5
10       | anna       | 5
```

The number in the invited_by column (default=0) is equal to the user_id who invited this person

So my Top 10 Page would display:

> TOP INVITERS:
>
> 1. Julia (4 invites)
> 2. John (3 invites)
> 3. Natasha (2 invites)

And so on...

My question now is, can I realize this with only one mysql query inclusive the total invites counter, eventually with a subquery and if yes, how this query must be?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_users ...... LIMIT 10"
```

And for performance reason, with this table style and million of users, is there any chance to sort out people that not yet invited someone, perhaps with an `in_array` check before?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group a self-join, then sort and limit the results:

```sql
SELECT   invitor.name, COUNT(*) AS invites
FROM     table_users invitor
    JOIN table_users invitee ON invitee.invited_by = invitor.user_id
GROUP BY invitor.user_id
ORDER BY invites DESC
LIMIT    10
```